# CodeIgniter throwing Error 404 when posting certain values through form submit

Tags: codeigniter, post, http-status-code-404

I'm using and older version of CodeIgniter (1.7.1), and I'm having problems submitting forms.

I have a form with some text fields and a textarea field which has a TinyMCE editor attached.

If I insert only text into textarea, everything works fine.

If I insert an image like this:

`<img src="htt://www.website.com/image.jpg" alt="" width="352" height="262" />`

Everything works fine as well.

The problem occurs whenever I insert an image through TinyMCE (and an upload manager). In this case, something like this is inserted:

`<img src="../../../tiny_upload/1.jpg" alt="" width="352" height="262" />`

When I hit the Post button, I get a "404 Page Not Found" page. I can't even print what is getting posted. It just throws this error immediately.

Thank you for your answers!

**EDIT:**

[View file](http://pastebin.com/CHHdxtPj)

[Controller file](http://pastebin.com/ZXPKBh38)

It is really old code (hence the 1.7 CI version), that is why it is a little messy.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `src` using JavaScript to the first one and then submit the form. That may work.

If you could post your code, we could more easily give you an answer for the 404 error message.

Comment: I could do that, but it's bugging me, why the error is showing up. I don't get it why the content of an textarea field would break CI?

OH, I edited my original post and added the complete view and controller files.

Comment: In your view, check the action="" you are passing a value to index and codeigniter considers it as a value passed through url. The mistake may be there. Try to print the values and use exit to display the output on the browser

Comment: That can't be the problem. As I explained in my original post, the error 404 occurs only, when I pass a certain value in my textarea.

I tried to echo the value of the textarea at the beginning of index function in controller, but it seems it doesn't even get there since it displays the error immediately.

Comment: i found a CI issue, v1.7, where when I end the textarea with a linefeed it goes to 404 immediately, but works without it